# 1 million concurrent database connections

Tags: google-cloud-sql

In https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/quotas, it mentioned that "Cloud Run services are limited to 100 connections to a Cloud SQL database.". Assume I deploy my service as Cloud Run, what's the right way to handle 1 million concurrent connections? Can cloud spanner enables this - I can't find documentation discussing maximum concurrent connections on cloud spanner maximum concurrent connection with Cloud Run.

Comment: Any system that needs a million concurrent connections is a site that needs an entire team of experts that can set up and maintain it. That's megacorporation-sized stuff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning) and cee i agree i believe that a huga huge cluster would be required

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to limits with Google Cloud Spanner, the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/quotas#limits_for_creating_reading_updating_and_deleting_data) points out the concurrent connections are limited up to 100 per session.

### Value/Limit

Commit size (including indexes)/ 100 MB

Concurrent reads per session/ 100

Mutations per commit (including indexes)/ 20,000

Concurrent Partitioned DML statements per database/ 20,000

### **Configuring the number of [sessions](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sessions#configuring_the_number_of_sessions)**

In general, we do not recommend modifying the default number of sessions used by the client libraries.
If you have a special workload, we recommend setting the lower bound to the number of expected concurrent transactions, and set the upper bound to an initial test number, such as 100. If the upper bound is not adequate, increase it. Increasing the number of active sessions uses additional resources on the Cloud Spanner database service, so failing to clean up unused sessions can degrade performance. We also recommend having no more than 100 sessions per gRPC channel.